# why do we need to demand the closure condition on the definition of a group?

Tags: group-theory

so far, this is the definition I saw in number of sources:

> A group $(G,·)$ is a nonempty set $G$ together with a binary operation
> $\cdot$ on $G$ such that the following conditions hold:
>
> (i) Closure: $\forall a,b\in G$, the element $a\cdot b$ is a uniquely
> defined element of G.
>
> (ii) Associativity: $\forall a,b,c\in G$, we have $a\cdot (b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c$
>
> (iii) Identity: There exists an identity element $e\in G$ such that
> $e\cdot a=a$ and $a\cdot e=a$
>
> $\forall a\in G$.
>
> (iv) Inverses: $\forall a\in G$ there exists an inverse element
> $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $a\cdot a^{-1}=e$ and $a^{-1}\cdot a=e$.

what I don't understand is why do we have to demand the closure condition if from the beginning we are given a binary operation on $G$ which means by definition that the result of the operation is in $G$. so is the demand of closure condition is redundant or am I missing something here? thanks.

Comment: A binary operation in general is $ \cdot : G \times G \to H$. A group requires $G=H$.

Comment: @Nitin that is not the definition of Binary operation I saw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct. I don't know where you have your information from, but it is enough to either say the operation $\cdot$ on G is binary $\Leftrightarrow \cdot : G \times G \rightarrow G $

or to say there is an operation $\cdot$ that combines two elements of $G$: $a\cdot b$such that the operation is closed $a\cdot b\in G$

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your definition of 'binary operation'.  Often it is defined to give a result in the same set.  Then closure isn't needed.  However, when looking at whether a subset is a subgroup, closure becomes important, since the inherited operation may not keep you within the subset.

Comment: but when I'm given the above definition I can't tell if the definition they meant for binary operation is that the result is in the same set or not.
so what should I understand from this definition?

Comment: Is the definition given in a book?  If so, you can see what the book's convention is on binary operation.  I would say that usually a binary operation stays in the same set.

Comment: this is also the definition I saw on wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given the common definition of 'binary operation' the definition above is redundant.  A quick Google search on the term binary operation gives many definitions which agree with yours.  However the term binary is often overloaded and might be construed as simply a function of two arguments like so: $f: A \times B \rightarrow C$.

It should be noted that the same definition with (i) removed is also redundant.  One can assume that a group only has a right inverse or a right unit, etc...

Another concern here is pedagogy.  It doesn't hurt to make it absolutely clear that $x \cdot y$ must be in $G$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $G$.  The definition you give, with the closure law explicitly stated, is more common in introduction sources.